# Sort values in specific order using a case statement for PowerBI

Tags: sql, ssms

I have a table with column that have products and count of products. I want to set the products with values so that when i sort the products on PowerBI they should appear in a certain order. For Example, I have 3 products, ADSL, Data, and Broadband. When you sort them out alphabetically they appear as ADSL, Broadband and Data. However I would like to sort them out in this Order Broadband, Data, ADSL. I know you have to use a CASE statement and I tried using it but it didnt work hence I am here.
Please assist.

Comment: Case expression, not statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a simple way is the use of case when in order by  in this way  ..

```
select your_column1, your_column2, your_column3
from your_table
ORDER BY CASE your_column
       WHEN 'Broadband' THEN 1
       WHEN 'Data' THEN 2
       WHEN 'ADSL' THEN 3
       ELSE 4
     END
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works but not the way I want it. On PowerBI when I load that table instead of showing product names it shows the numbers. Anyway I can swap them around?

Comment: what  do you mean with "instead of showing product names it shows the numbers"  .?  my  answer  manage the order  by ...  based on the info you provided   for the showing name you  can select the column (and the value ) you prefer .. eventually update your question and add a proper data sample and the expected  result  ..